# How to find duplicate records within the same timeperiod in R

Tags: r, time, duplicates

I'm trying to find duplicate records in a dataframe of behavioural data in R. I need to find rows that have the same values based on more than one column and that have been recorded within the same hour.

For example: Rows 1-2 and 3-4 below have the same values in the columns Date, Observer and FocalID and have been recorded within the same hour.

```
    N  Date         Time        Observer   FocalID 
    1  20180520     07:05:00    VR         JK
    2  20180520     07:50:00    VR         JK
    3  20180521     07:50:00    JD         CJD
    4  20180521     08:25:00    JD         CJD
```

I have tried the following code, but it won't work. A reason is that find_duplicates (hablar package) does not accept an interval, but only dataframe columns.

```
Time <- as.POSIXct (df$Time, format="%H:%M:%S")
span60 <- (Time - minutes(60)) %--% (Time + minutes(60))
df %>% find_duplicates (Date, Observer, FocalID, Time %within% span60)
```

Any kind of help would be very welcome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is your expected output. Here is one way which will give a unique `ID` to every "duplicates".

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::unite(DateTime, Date, Time, sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(DateTime = lubridate::ymd_hms(DateTime)) %>%
  group_by(Observer, FocalID) %>%
  mutate(grp = floor(difftime(DateTime, first(DateTime), units = 'hour'))) %>%
  group_by(grp, .add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(ID = cur_group_id()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp)
  
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#      N DateTime            Observer FocalID    ID
#  <int> <dttm>              <chr>    <chr>   <int>
#1     1 2018-05-20 07:05:00 VR       JK          2
#2     2 2018-05-20 07:50:00 VR       JK          2
#3     3 2018-05-21 07:50:00 JD       CJD         1
#4     4 2018-05-21 08:25:00 JD       CJD         1
```

All the rows with similar ID's can be considered as a part of one group.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(N = 1:4, Date = c(20180520L, 20180520L, 20180521L, 
20180521L), Time = c("07:05:00", "07:50:00", "07:50:00", "08:25:00"
), Observer = c("VR", "VR", "JD", "JD"), FocalID = c("JK", "JK", 
"CJD", "CJD")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: That's a little hacky because it's so fully dependent on the first observed timestamp and it only works with the limited rows posted as an example, I think. Also, you're hard cutting at date boundaries which is a hard assumption.. I think for each row, *any* other row within a window of ±60 minutes can be a duplicate candidate...

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this and it works well! It looks like it works on the whole dataframe, not only with the rows posted as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem as trying to find any rows that have duplicate values in `Observer` and `FocalID`, while being within 60 minutes of each other.
The following solution works across date boundaries:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Observer, FocalID) %>%
  mutate(
    dt = as_datetime(paste(Date, Time), tz = "UTC"),
    dt_frame = interval(dt - minutes(60), dt + minutes(60), "UTC"),
    which_duplicates = map(dt_frame, ~N[which(dt %within% .x)], N = N, dt = dt),
    has_duplicates = map_lgl(which_duplicates, ~length(.x) > 1)
  )
```

If you don't want this to group observations across midnight and keep days separate, just add `Date` to the `group_by` statement.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this, but it says that it couldn't find the 'map' function. I've loaded dplyr and lubridate as you said.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I forgot that map needs the `purrr` library. I'll add it above. Thanks for highlighting